# Angular Flex Layout: How to set the width of the form to the father container?

Tags: angular, html, angular-flex-layout

The form in the code below is not displayed properly. I want it to fill the whole container (which is what Angular flex layout normally does, I believe), but instead, it only fills about a third of the whole container. 
[image]

I have tried to apply "size: 100%" to form, div and mat-form-field, but none of these methods works.

```
<div class="container"
fxLayout="row"
fxLayout.sm="column"
fxLayout.xs="column"
fxLayoutAlign.gt-md="space-around center"
fxLayoutGap="20px" 
fxLayoutGap.xs="0">

<div fxFlex *ngIf="dish">
  ...
</div>

<div fxFlex *ngIf="dish">
    <h3>
      <b>Comments</b>
    </h3>
    <mat-list *ngIf="dish.comments">
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of dish.comments">
          <p matline>
          <span>{{comment.comment}}<br></span>
          <span>{{comment.rating}} Stars<br></span>
          <span>-- {{comment.author}} {{comment.date | date}}</span>
          </p>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>

    <form novalidate #fform="ngForm" [formGroup]="commentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <p>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="name" placeholder="name" type="text" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.name">{{formErrors.name}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <p>
      <mat-slider thumbLabel tickInterval="1" min="0" max="5"></mat-slider>
    </p>
    <p>
      <mat-form-field>
        <textarea matInput formControlName="comment" placeholder="comment" rows=8 required></textarea>
        <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.comment">{{formErrors.comment}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
      <button type="submit" mat-button class="background-primary text-floral-white">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div [hidden]="dish">
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner><h4>Loading . . . Please Wait</h4>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add a StackBlitz example with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can I do this if the code involves flex layout and lots of data binding? @Roy

Comment: Can u take a look via browser devtools from where the rule comes that restricts the form size? whats about the padding seems for me like the forms or the container has to much?